# How to populate unit tests field in gnome-builder with custom tests?

Tags: python, unit-testing, gnome-builder

I am trying to build my first `gtk` application using `python3` in the gnome builder `IDE`, and there is an auto generated field for `unit tests` that I would like to take advantage of to keep my workspace neat. However,I can't seem to figure out how to use this section, and it is only populated with auto generated tests (that I cannot find the source of). Any advice would be appreciated. I'm able to make my own unit tests, but running it the "intended" way in builder would probably be best.

Answer (score 0):

Unit Test section in gnome-builder shows tests described in meson.build files.

Example from gnome application template:

```
desktop_utils = find_program('desktop-file-validate', required: false)
if desktop_utils.found()
  test('Validate desktop file', desktop_utils, args: [desktop_file])
endif
```

Meson Unit tests documentation: https://mesonbuild.com/Unit-tests.html